How to fix mamba install timeout error on ubuntu
I am using a bash script to create a conda environment for a project. The bash script uses mamba create command. I have installed mamba using their official guide. However, when I run the script, I get an error saying that;
RuntimeError: Download error (28) Timeout was reached [https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/cudnn-8.9.7.29-hbc23b4c_3.conda]
    Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds

Here I have attached the output from my terminal. Please note the list of packages section was removed to make it shorter.
> bash setup-env.sh my-conda-env

Looking for: ['transformers', 'python=3.10', 'pytorch', 'fairscale', 'dask-mongo', 'torchaudio', 'pytorch-cuda=11.7', 'iopath', 'cudatoolkit=11.7']

pytorch/linux-64                                            Using cache
pytorch/noarch                                              Using cache
nvidia/linux-64                                             Using cache
nvidia/noarch                                               Using cache
conda-forge/linux-64                                        Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
iopath/linux-64                                               No change
iopath/noarch                                                 No change
warning  libmamba Package tarball '/home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs/ucx-1.14.1-h64cca9d_5.conda' is invalid
warning  libmamba Package tarball '/home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs/libopenblas-0.3.27-pthreads_h413a1c8_0.conda' is invalid
warning  libmamba Package tarball '/home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs/libgoogle-cloud-2.12.0-hac9eb74_1.conda' is invalid
warning  libmamba Package tarball '/home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs/libcufft-10.7.2.124-h4fbf590_0.tar.bz2' is invalid
warning  libmamba Package tarball '/home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs/libnpp-11.7.4.75-0.tar.bz2' is invalid
Transaction

  Prefix: /home/akila-i/miniforge3/envs/picssmart

  Updating specs:

   - transformers
   - python=3.10
   - pytorch
   - fairscale
   - dask-mongo
   - torchaudio
   - pytorch-cuda=11.7
   - iopath
   - cudatoolkit=11.7


  Package                    Version  Build                     Channel           Size
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Install:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
-- List is removed as its too long --

Summary:

  Install: 201 packages

  Total download: 3GB

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

This is error report

Download error (28) Timeout was reached [https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/cudnn-8.9.7.29-hbc23b4c_3.conda]
Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 959, in exception_converter
        raise e
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 952, in exception_converter
        exit_code = _wrapped_main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 898, in _wrapped_main
        result = do_call(parsed_args, p)
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 767, in do_call
        exit_code = create(args, parser)
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 602, in create
        return install(args, parser, "create")
      File "/home/akila-i/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 558, in install
        transaction.fetch_extract_packages()
    RuntimeError: Download error (28) Timeout was reached [https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/cudnn-8.9.7.29-hbc23b4c_3.conda]
    Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds

`$ /home/akila-i/miniforge3/bin/mamba create -n my-conda-env transformers python=3.10 pytorch fairscale dask-mongo torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 iopath cudatoolkit=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia -c iopath -c conda-forge -y`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/akila-i/miniforge3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/akila-i/miniforge3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/akila-i/miniforge3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/akila-i/miniforge3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                     PATH=/home/akila-i/miniforge3/bin:/home/akila-
                          i/miniforge3/condabin:/usr/bin/flutter/bin:/home/akila-
                          i/.nvm/versions/node/v22.0.0/bin:/home/akila-i/.console-ninja/.bin:/ho
                          me/akila-
                          i/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/
                          bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/akila-i/miniforge3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/akila-i/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/akila-i/miniforge3/.condarc
          conda version : 24.3.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.14.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=icelake
                          __conda=24.3.0=0
                          __cuda=12.2=0
                          __glibc=2.39=0
                          __linux=6.8.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/akila-i/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/akila-i/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/iopath/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/iopath/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /home/akila-i/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /home/akila-i/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/akila-i/miniforge3/envs
                          /home/akila-i/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.3.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.10.14 Linux/6.8.0-31-generic ubuntu/24.04 glibc/2.39 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.8
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>



I have tried reinstalling conda as well. But I could not get this resolved. Anyone knows why it is occuring and how to solve?

It seems that you can disable the error on speed limit by setting the following flag before run the script
export MAMBA_NO_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT=1

